# Django: Pass LDAP Credentials to 3rd Party SDK

Tags: django, ldap

I'm new to Django and developing an app for internal use. I have configured it with the `django_auth_ldap` module for authenticating to LDAP. Once the user has authenticated there are automation tasks for them to execute that use 3rd party SDKs (also LDAP auth required). Below is a simple function in my views.py config that will create a session using the SDK, but is there a way to pass the authentication of the user to the function?

**views.py**

```
def create_session(hostname, username, password):
    """Create an API Session using an SDK."""
    session = SDK(hostname, username=username, password=password)
    return session

@login_required
def list_info(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            session = create_session(form.cleaned_data['host'], ?username?, ?password?)
            host_info = session.get()
            note = 'Information from {}: '.format(form.cleaned_data['host'])
            dataset = pd.json_normalize(host_info)
            session.invalidate_cookie()
        else:
            note = 'API call has failed. Try again.'
        return render(request, 'list_info.html', {'form':form,
                                                'note':note,
                                                'dataset':dataset.to_html(index=False, justify='left',
                                                                          classes='table table-stripe')})
    else:
        form = Form()
        return render(request, 'list_info.html', {'form':form})
```

I originally created CLI apps using the `click` module but have been trying to convert them to Django. Is there an easier approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a workaround to this issue. I decided to create a service account to handle the 3rd party SDK actions. When a user executes an automation task the username will be recorded into the Django PostgreSQL database as well as a post to our Slack channel with a description of what was executed.